# core dump in SDL, where?

Tags: c++, sdl

Just in the first lines happened the **** core dump.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_Surface *screen;
SDL_Surface *background;
SDL_Surface *tablero;
SDL_Surface *x;
SDL_Surface *o; 
SDL_Rect posFondo;
//SDL_Rect posPlayerX[5];
//SDL_Rect posPlayerO[5];
SDL_Event suceso;

// Definir
x = SDL_LoadBMP("players.bmp");
o = SDL_LoadBMP("players.bmp");
tablero = SDL_LoadBMP("tablero.bmp");

/* Clear bg colors */
SDL_SetColorKey(x, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY,
    SDL_MapRGB(x->format, 255, 0, 255));

SDL_SetColorKey(o, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY,
    SDL_MapRGB(o->format, 255, 0, 255));

SDL_SetColorKey(tablero, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY,
    SDL_MapRGB(tablero->format, 255, 0, 255));
/* END */

screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(600, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
if (screen == NULL) { return 0; }

/* Positions */
posFondo.x = 0;
posFondo.y = 0;

while (true) {
    SDL_BlitSurface(tablero, NULL, screen, &posFondo);
    //SDL_BlitSurface

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&suceso)) {
        if (suceso.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            break; break;
        }
    } 
    SDL_Flip(screen);   
    SDL_Delay ( 5 );
}
```

I can't find the problem, I try to delete some things and add dynamic variables (new, delete types) and nope...

Comment: There is precisely no way in which anybody could help you debug this code right now.  You need to provide specific detail of the error you're getting.  Consider running your program inside `gdb` or some other debugger.

Comment: Why are you calling SDL_Init twice?

Answer (score 3):

I only see two errors in your code. For starters, there is no need to call SDL_Init() twice. When you call SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING), you're already initializing video. Get rid of the second call to SDL_Init(). The second issue in your code would be in your:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&suceso)){
    if(suceso.type == SDL_QUIT){
        break; break;
    }
}
```

When you call the first break, it exits the while loop. The second break is never used. Because of this, I'm going to guess you encounter a situation in which the loop never ends. Here is what I would recommend for your loop:

```
bool quit = false;
while (!quit) {
    SDL_BlitSurface(tablero, NULL, screen, &posFondo);
    //SDL_BlitSurface

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&suceso)) {
        if (suceso.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            quit = true;
        }
    } 
    SDL_Flip(screen);   
    SDL_Delay ( 5 );
}
```

EDIT: You should probably also initialize your SDL_Surface*'s to NULL.

EDIT#2: There's really no need to call SDL_BlitSurface() and SDL_Flip() every frame unless your tablero surface is going to change. If you use SDL_WaitEvent() instead of SDL_PollEvents(), you can update your screen and such whenever the user does something, rather than all the time for no real reason.